# Java: Extract digits from a number without using % and string

Tags: java, numbers, digit

How to extract all the digits from a number without using modulus and String ? e.g. 1234 should return 1, 2, 3 and 4 separately.

Comment: what is 1234 type of?? String??

Comment: you can create a method to simulate `%` if it's ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you don't want to use modulo, but here you go:

I assume 1234 is of type `int`. You can divide this number by 10, giving you 123. Afterwards, you subtract the original number by 10*123, i.e. 1234 - 10*123. This gives you the last digit, 4. Afterwards, you do the same on 123 and so on, until the number divided by 10 is 0. In the end, it will just simulate a modulo operator.

Comment: Thanks Tobias. It was an interview question asked to one of my friend @ Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

given you are working with an array you can convert the array to an `IntStream` and using the eg. `.filter(%3)` method to filter out the int's you dont want

Answer (score 0):

```
    int n=78912;
    while(n>0)
    {
        System.out.print(n-10*(n/10));
        n=n/10;
    }
```

**Output:** 21987